# Objects wont fade in with IE

Tags: jquery

Not sure what's wrong, but elements wont fade in on http://kimberlywarner.com/

```
$('#photos').width(galleryWidth).animate(
        {
            opacity: 1
        }, 
        1500, 
        'easeInOutQuint',
        function() 
        {
            // Animation complete.
        }
    );
```

Comment: Did you try `fadeIn/fadeOut` or `fadeTo` functions?

Comment: have you tried putting the `script` tags in the `head`? IE can be funny about where things go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set it to 0 first because IE does not support opacity by default (*jquery will handle the internals*).

```
$('#photos').width(galleryWidth).css('opacity',0).animate(
        {
            opacity: 1
        }, 
        1500, 
        'easeInOutQuint',
        function() 
        {
            // Animation complete.
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You're telling jQuery to animated based on `opacity`. Internet Explorer < 9 doesn't support the CSS `opacity` property, opting for proprietary filters. If you use the relevant `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods, jQuery will apply the IE-specific filters for you automatically.

Comment: can I fadeIn/Out with easeInOutQuint ?